# Count Of Each Rows In SQL Server 2008 Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 where there is a column of `product`s: example rows would be

```
product1
product1
product1
product2
product2
product3
```

I want to get the count of each distinct `product`: (`product1=3,product2=2,product3=1`) from the table. How do I query for this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select [column name],count(*) from [table name] group by [column name]
```

Comment: Mr.Arun, if it works fine, atleast appreciate work of person who had given the answer !
You can give him upward if you want !!!